# Find temp space used by query in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to find temp space used by a query? Tried with Explain and Explain extended but that doesn't show any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one thing you could do is monitor the temp directory while you are running a query.

Howerver, there are specific types of queries/situations that will cause temp files to be created (not all).

The answer at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30635 tells you which kinds.

Comment: Thanks, what if the temp space is not large enough to be written to disk?

Comment: Then your query cannot finish :( . I've had this problem, had to move to a bigger disk.

Comment: How to monitor this when temp is not being written on disk? Please note that mysql write to disk when temp space requirement increases a threshold value (tmp_table_size and max-heap-table-size).

Comment: If it's not being written to disk, are you asking what the memory usage is?

Comment: I mean ram memory usage?

Comment: Yes.. I workaround this by decreasing value tmp_table_size to minimum and then monitoring the disk... but I would like to know what is the ram usage if mysql is not writing to disk?

Comment: Maybe monitor mysql instance ram usage multiple times while running the query. However, obviously on a server you only use. Your solution is also good to decrease the treshold.

Comment: hmm... isn't there any monitoring tool for mysql which can give this info?

Comment: I have no idea to tell you the truth - I'd have to google it in addition to googling how you can calculate memory usage per row based on field types from schema.